# Was Critical Mass (2001) authorised to use footage from Terminator 2 and Universal Soldier?

Tags: terminator-2-judgment-day, universal-soldier, critical-mass

The film [*Critical Mass*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0218126/) (2001) contains a significant amount of footage  taken directly from two big-budget scifi films; *Terminator 2: Judgment Day* and *Universal Soldier*. The film went straight-to-DVD but certainly made it onto TV screens as I recall seeing it on Sky Movies at least once.

Given the ***extensive*** use (10+ minutes each) of edited scenes from these copyrighted and very recognisable movies, why didn't they get sued into oblivion by the makers of T2 and UniSol? Did they have permission to use these clips, or was there some sort of legal black hole that made this footage fair game, noting that [T2 footage was used](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kyUGYJzUBw) in at least one other film made in the same year, *[Militia](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0217654/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0_tt_6_nm_2_q_Militia)* (2000).

Comment: Also, a plot stolen from https://www.moriareviews.com/sciencefiction/project-shadowchaser-ii-1994.htm

Comment: Have you checked the credits of the film for 'used by permission' notes?

Comment: @JonCuster - My copy of the film doesn't have the credits

Comment: @Valorum have you perhaps checked imdb dot com or other websites that offer film technical details?

Comment: @SottoVoce - IMDB is, as usual, pretty useless. It mentions that the film uses footage from T2 and UniSol, but doesn't give any additional commentary

Comment: I wonder if the movie lost money and the legal entity that would be considered liable is bankrupt, and maybe there’s no point in suing a bankrupt entity?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Even if that were the case, Tri-Star would vigorously sue to prevent the film from being shown on commercial television.

Comment: Maybe they paid licensing fees that were less than the cost of shooting the footage themselves? https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-use-footage-from-someone-elses-movie-in-your-own-movie

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Big studios rarely licence film clips of this length. There's ten solid minutes of footage from each film that's been edited into Critical Mass

Comment: Yeah I skimmed through *Critical Mass*. Some amazing helicopter stunts from *T2* used. I mean if I were James Cameron I might be a bit perturbed. Perhaps the studio feels they were paid fairly for the solid ten minute excerpts? I'm just guessing, hence comments. I've seen such stuff before. I remember watching an episode of *JAG* with lots of footage from *Clear and Present Danger* in it - the ambush scene. So it happens and I've just assumed there's a mechanism for it - such as paying licensing fees or something.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I've twitted at the actor, director and writer. Hopefully one of them will be able to shed some light.